# Comparing Negative Sharpe Ratio

Tags: sharpe-ratio

It is widely accepted that the higher the Sharpe Ratio, the better. But, how do we compare two strategy with negative Sharpe Ratio?

Suppose we have two trading strategy $A$ and $B$. Consider the following scenarios:

**Scenario 1:**
Assume that strategy $A$ and $B$ have the same **excess return** of $-10\%$. But, the volatility of strategy $A$ is $5\%$ and strategy $B$ is $10\%$. Then, the Sharpe Ratios of $A$ and $B$ are $-2$ and $-1$, respectively.

**Scenario 2:**
Assume that strategy $A$ and $B$ have the same **volatility** of $10\%$. But, the excess return of strategy $A$ is $-20\%$ and strategy $B$ is $-10\%$. Then, the Sharpe Ratios of $A$ and $B$ are $-2$ and $-1$, respectively.

In scenario 1, strategy $A$ is favorable since it has a lower risk while yielding the same return as strategy $B$ and $SR_A < SR_B$.

While in scenario 2, strategy $B$ is favorable since it has higher excess return for taking the same risk as strategy $A$. But, still $SR_A < SR_B$.

Comment: In scenario 2: $SR_A = -2$ and $SR_A = -1$ right? Then your last sentence is false.

Comment: @BobJansen oh yes, thank you for spotting. I have edited it

Comment: Then the problem disappears right?

Comment: I don't think so. Since in scenario 1 $A$ is better but $SR_A < SR_B$. While in scenario 2 $B$ is better but $SR_A < SR_B$. Which means higher Sharpe Ratio doesn't mean better when the ratio is negative. Am I missing something?

Comment: In the paper "Interpreting the Sharpe Ratio when excess returns are negative" the authors claim that sharpe ratio should be interpreted probabilistically and in that setting you should choose the fund with highest SR because such fund has the highest probability of beating the risk free rate. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/285365236_Interpreting_the_Sharpe_ratio_when_excess_returns_are_negative

Comment: Also one of the advantages of the "M Squared" measure is that it can be interpreted even when the Sharpe Ratio is negative.